# .Htaccess Rewrites. Magento related

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I have an URL like this need to be redirected:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/Category/Product-Page.html
```

Redirect to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/product-page.html
```

Couple things to be mentioned here:

```
1. "Category" must gone.
2. Uppercase letters must become lowercase letters.
3. I have couple thousand of these kind of urls need to be redirected.
```

I am using a well-known .htaccess codes that can be found online to replace all uppercases to lowercases with a conditional loop. Even though it is not recommended to add extra rewrites on top of this code. I have managed to add an additional code on the very top.

```
RewriteRule ^Category/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^Category/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

It works as I expected, but my VSP provider sent me an urgent notice saying that my .htaccess rewrite rules causing some sort of memory leak that eat up all the memories on the shared server. My first reaction is this.

```
RewriteRule ^Category/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So I tried to put this rule after the initial uppercase to lowercase loop and made sure the Category to be category. Everything stopped working. Not even uppercase to lowercase rules.

Not sure if you can totally understand my question here, but please try to help me out a bit.

Comment: Do you have access to your vhost config file?

Comment: No I don't. I know it would be much easier that way... But I have to stick with .htaccess file.

Comment: Can you use a htaccess/PHP alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having a hard time with your host because of the performance it's doing using the current .htaccess. Maybe you can use this `PHP/htaccess` hybrid method.

Use this .htaccess rules instead of your current .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# check if Category is in the path and route it through the php function
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /Category
RewriteRule ^Category/(.*)$ rewrite-strtolower.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# if upper case route it through the php function
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Category
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite-strtolower.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

Then create a PHP file called `rewrite-strtolower.php` in the website root and put this code inside.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    unset($_GET['url']);
    $params = http_build_query($_GET);
    if(strlen($params)) {
        $params = '?' . $params;
    }
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . strtolower($url) . $params, true, 301);
    exit;
}
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die('Unable to convert the URL to lowercase.');

?>
```

See if this will work for you and can get around the memory issue.

I borrowed part of this solution from [here](http://simonholywell.com/post/2012/11/force-lowercase-urls-rewrite-php.html).

Comment: Very nice explanation. It solved my problem. One thing that I need to modify is to comment our the last 'RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]'

Comment: Ok yeah you can comment it out. If this solves it please accept the answer to know it helped.

Comment: After I run couple stress tests, I will accept your answer asap. Thank you very much!